# The difference between the Render Bundles at head and body in MVC View file, _Layout.cshtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to use jQuery UI DatePicker in ASP.NET MVC.

It's work by a website tutorial:[How to Use jQuery UI DatePicker in ASP.NET MVC 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZXj9ojFFk8).

The step as follow:

Step 1:
Modify the bundles from body to head in _Layout.cshtml file.

```
    <head>
       ...
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    </head>
```

Step 2:
To create textbox for datetime picker function select datetime.

Step 3:
To include jQuery "link" and "script" from [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) Quick Access.

Step 4:
To set the function showing datetime when user selected datetime.

PS:The detail from step 2 to step 4 in the hyperlink above. And all in Index.cshtml file.

> The question is that why I have to modify the bundles scripts section to head?(step 1)
>
> Why it doesn't work when I set the bundles scripts in the body section?
>
> What difference between bundles scripts in body and head?

Comment: It should work either way.

Comment: I try many times to set the bundles scripts at _Layout.cshtml body section in a new asp.net MVC project. But it don't work really.....

Comment: Personally I always place my `@Scripts.Render()` immediately before the closing `</body>` tag (although there are arguments for and against). If its not working, you need to show the code you have tried. Possibly you have the scripts in the wrong order, or have duplicated scripts.

Comment: All code I have tried is follow the hyperlink in my article(youtube tutorial vedio) in a default MVC project.  And the position of '@Scripts.Render(~/../bundles)' in MVC default project is the same with your coding habit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the script links anywhere in the document within . Where you should place is arguable.

The only think you should make sure whether you have placed the script in right order. For example JqueryUI plugin depends on Jquery plugin. So you should always include Jquery first then Jquery UI.

In the video Visual Studio placed Render module at the end of the page the author just decided to place it at the start of the page and then when he added the Jquery UI he added it on the index.cshtml to render the jquery ui after jquery

If you want to keep the render at the bottom of _Layout page you should add jquery UI link in the _Layout page after the Render Section module.

**Example**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I realize that I have to declare the jQuery at _Layout page before add the jQuery UI ay index page after your answer. But here are two more question want to ask you. First: How to add jquery UI link in the _Layout page after the Render Section module? Secnd: I really don't know how to make sure that I placed the script in right order?

Comment: I have added an example to make sure that jquery ui always renders after jquery.

Comment: Sorry too late to respond you!!!  I have tried to set different place the script. And then that I am realize how to use by your answer!  Thanks a lot!!